# Better way to find duplicate on PK field : Search for duplicate or try to insert?

Tags: sql, database

I want to know which option is more performant and quick :
When trying to insert a new row in my database, I wanna know if one the values (that is on a PK column), already exisys in the database and is a duplicate. If it exists, I do nothing, if it doesn't I insert it. In order to achieve this is it better to :

- Look for the field in the database with something like

```
SELECT username, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY username, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and see if there are results

- Simply try to insert a value for the field and see if the database responds with an error (Key already exists)

Thanks

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: If it really is the primary key, it can't have duplicates. Is there any constraint on the column or an index?

Comment: Hi @tinazmu

I know it's not possible, the column has restreint yes, it's a PK
But what I wanna know is that in my Java program, which way is better when I wanna insert à new value (that I don't know if it exists or not) in order to insert it only if it's not existant : search for it, or try to insert it and see if the database retrieves an error

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Which way is better depends on how the rdbms product handles it, compared to how a select query to check if it already exists. You have not specified which database product you use, but even if you had, it would be hard for us to say because it depends on a number of things like how the uniqueness is enforced, if through a unique index, how well the index is maintained, etc. In general, exception handling is costly, so I would use check and insert (instead of check and fail if duplicate). The best way is to experiment

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a primary key then it cannot have duplicates, so there is no point in finding the duplicate. However if you wish to find any other field exists, other that primary key then you have no choice that doing a simple where clause.

Also, you can have composite unique key constraint so you don't have to worry about the duplicate for multiple column.
Just to find if there is value exists. you can use

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_employee WHERE firstname = 'some other name')
INSERT INTO tbl_employee (firstname)
values('some other name')

--but be aware of performance, when the number of records are high in tbl_employee
```

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood my question.
I wanna know which way is better to know if a value already exists

Comment: using EXISTS keyword is what I know in SQL.